# Test koin in ktor application

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

Hi im trying to write ktor testcases with koin dependency injection and in the tutorial im watching the person uses `withTestApplication(moduleFunction = {install(Routing)})` Though `withTestApplication()` is deprecated and so the `moduleFunction` part does not work with the new `testApplication()` setup what should i do instead is my question? this is the tutorial im watching [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufoTXJ0eRQY&list=UUMOKNTZMRHPLXfqlbdOI7mCkg&index=28)
i have also checked

https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html#testing-api

and

https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-test/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure a module using `testApplication` use the `application` method:

```
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import kotlin.test.Test

class KtorTest {
    @Test
    fun test() = testApplication {
        application {
            install(Routing)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The install doesnt work it says fun <P : Pipeline<*, ApplicationCall>, B : Any, F : Any> install(plugin: Plugin<Application, Routing, Routing>, configure: Routing.() -> Unit = ...): Unit' can't be called in this

Comment: I've added `import` statements

Comment: Ah thanks i am now stuck on Handlerequest but see if i can figure it out myself thanks for the help though! :D